# CreateJS Performance issue when rendering in a canvas that is displayed on mobile

Tags: three.js, createjs, easeljs

I have a very specific issue. I am doing a demo in VR with three.js where I want to display 2D data. The data that will be displayed is dynamic (Text info) and needs to be animated.

Animate CC providing a nice suite of tools is an easy choice for this. With three.js, the way I found to add some 2D animation in the world, was to create a plane, add a texture from a canvas I created, which I update on RAF. No problem as of now.

The canvas I'm rendering is also the one that I create my stage from. Here the issue : Whatever the animation is (even an empty stage) I see a drop in framerate of about 15, as soon as I add the eventlistener on tick for the stage update. I tried many things (like not even adding the mesh, onto which I draw the canvas, to my scene) And If the eventlistener is added, I see my fps take a hit.

Whether the animation is "heavy" or not, I see this drop in framerate. And that drop is a big issue in VR since staying on 60 FPS is pretty much a must have at this point.

Any lead on what I could do to make this better ? Thank you !

Comment: so you redraw a 2d canvas each frame?  2d canvas is very slow - that is probably your bottle-neck, find a way to animate in 3D only so that the GPU takes over the load

Comment: Even if the canvas isn't even renderer on the texture I get that hit, so I kinda doubt that that is the real problem here. I would add that I tried rendering a WebGL animation on that same texture in a canvas and I don't get that performance problem. (Though I need some of the features Flash Canvas offers that WebGL export doesn't have.... Text, Transparent background)

Comment: rendering the canvas is not the issue, it is the canvas that is slow = drawing onto canvas2D is slow, it is not obvious from your question or comment, but if you update some 2d canvas every frame i would guess that is the problem